# How to decide if a webpage is about a specific topic or not?

Tags: regex, nlp, jsoup, semantic-web

I am trying to write a code which can take the source html of a web page then decide what kind of web page it is. I am intrested in deciding if the web page is about academic courses or not. A naive first approach that I have is to check if the text has words which can be related like (course, instructor, teach,...) and decide that it is about an academic course if it achieves enough hits.

Even though, I need some ideas how to achieve that more efficiently.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Sorry for my English.

Comment: This question is too broad for StackOverflow. You could search through [DataScience.SE](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [ComputerScience.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com) instead and if you didn’t find a solution, ask there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many approaches to classifying a text, but first: a web page should be converted to plain text either using a dump way of removing all the HTML tags and reading what's left, or using smarter ways of identifying the main parts of the page that would contain all the useful text, in the latter case you can use some HTML5 elements like `<article>`, read about the [HTML5 structural elements here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements).

Then you can try any of the following methods, depending on really how far you are willing to go with your implementation:

- Like you mentioned, a simple search for relative words, but that would give you a very low success rate.
- Improve the solution above by passing the tokens of the texts to a lexical analyzer and focus on the nouns, nouns usually have the highest value - *I will try to find the resource of this but I'm sure I read it somewhere while implementing a similar project* -, this might improve the rate a little.
- Improve more by looking at the origin of the word, you can use a **Morphological Analyzer** to do so, and this way you can tell that the word "papers" is the same as "paper". That can improve a little.
- You can also use an ontology of words like [Word Net](http://www.w3.org/TR/wordnet-rdf/), and you can then start looking whether the words in the document are descendants of one of the words you're looking for, or the other way around but going up means genaralizing which would affect the precision. e.g. you can tell that the word "kitten" is related to the word "cat" and so you can assume that since the document talks about "kittens" then it talks about "cats".

All the above depends on you setting a defined list of keywords that you would base your decision on. But life doesn't work that way usually, that's why we use machine learning. And the basic idea would be that you would get a set of documents and manually tag/categorize/classify them, and then feed those documents to your program as a training set and let your program learn on them, afterwards your program would be able to apply what it learned in tagging other untagged documents. If you decide to go with this option then you can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417982/text-classification-methods-svm-and-decision-tree) and this [Quora question](http://www.quora.com/Natural-Language-Processing/What-is-the-best-approach-for-text-categorization) and the possibilities are endless.

And assuming you speak Arabic I would share [a paper of the project I worked on here](http://bit.ly/1gfIjIy) if you're interested, but it is in Arabic and deals with the challenges of classifying Arabic text.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) It is very helpful. I speak Arabic yes :)))

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about web programming as a c language programmer, but I would make sure it checks for different domain name suffixes. .edu is one most universities use, .gov for government pages and so on, then no need to scan a page. But surly the way to achieve highest accuracy is o use these methods, but create a way for users to correct the app, this info can be hosted on a webserver and a page can be cross referenced against that data base. Its always great to use your customer as an improvement tool!

another way would be to see if you can cross reference it with search engines that categorise in their index. For example google collates academic abstracts in google scholar. You could see if the web age is present in that data base?

Hope this helped! If I have any other ideas you will be the first to know!

Comment: Thank you for your help :) but this is not exactly what I am searching for. I need a way which goes through the content of the webpage as I am searching in topics related to NLP, Semantic Web,....

Answer (score 1):

Run text thru sequence-finding algorithm.

Basics of algorithm: you take some amount of definitely `academic course` related web-pages, clean them and search them for frequently met word sequences (2-5 words). Then by hand remove common word sequences, that are not related to `academic course` directly. By examining how much of that sequences are met in some web-page you can with some precission find out, if it's contents is well-related to source of test word sequences.

*Note: Testet web pages must be properly cleaned up. Clean page contents from anything unrelated - delete `link`, `script` tags&contents, remove tags itself (but leave text in image's `alt`/`title` attributes) and so on. Context to examine should be title, meta keywords & description + cleaned contents of page. Next step is to stem text.*

Comment: Thank you very much :) That's very helpful.

Comment: Can you please provide some more explanation or examples about this algorithm?